# Resolving imports when trying to test Typescript in angular using mocha test framework

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to integrate mocha testing framework to my existing Angular application. I have got the setup working as intended, but as I want to test components, services etc, I'm trying to use the Angular Test Bed configuration, so I wanted to write the test files in ***typescript*** and it produces errors for me.

I tried different approaches which gives me different errors. First, I installed **mocha** & **@types/mocha** & then updated the **package.json** also. Then, as I ran the ***npm test***, it produced errors. I tried installing **ts-node** and requiring it in the test configuration and running the test, but it didn't fix this. Then I tried to change the compiler module and then another error produced. I tried searching SO and also many other website, but the solutions did not help me.

This is the first attempt. My **test.ts** file

```js
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { LoginComponent } from 'src/app/login/login.component';

let assert = require('assert');

describe('LoginComponent', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
    let component: LoginComponent;

    beforeEach(function() {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [LoginComponent]
        })
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('create Login component', () => {
        assert.notNull(component);
    });
});
```

and the following error stacktrace was produced.

```
D:\Testing\cenium-web\test\login.component.test.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:330:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:327:14)
    at Mocha.run (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:804:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:207:16)
    at exports.runMocha (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:300:13)
    at Object.exports.handler.argv [as handler] (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:296:3)
    at Object.runCommand (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:242:26)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1087:28)
    at Object.parse (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js:63:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:10:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

This is my **tsconfig.json** file.

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "types": ["node", "mocha"],
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
        "paths": {
            "cComponents": ["dist/cComponents"],
            "cComponents/*": ["dist/cComponents/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

#### Then I tried to change the compiler module from ***es2015*** to ***commonjs***.

This caused a different error in paths I think

```
Error: Cannot find module 'src/app/login/login.component'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Testing\cenium-web\test\login.component.test.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:330:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:327:14)
    at Mocha.run (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:804:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:207:16)
    at exports.runMocha (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:300:13)
    at Object.exports.handler.argv [as handler] (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:296:3)
    at Object.runCommand (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:242:26)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1087:28)
    at Object.parse (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js:63:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Testing\cenium-web\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:10:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I got a point stating I have to use something like **webpack** to resolve these modules. Is this correct? If possible can someone direct me to a solution?

I want to use the **TestBed** configuration in my existing test files in order to test my components. It is much appreciated if anyone can help me as I am new to testing. Thanks in advance. Hope the info is enough.